# Probability of being hired out of 3 people

Tags: probability

Question: A company will hire either one of James,Bill and Michael. Bill is an undergraduate, therefore his chance of being hired is 20% more than James and 20% more than Michael. What is the probability that Bill will be hired?

Attempt:
$$
P(B)=1.2P(J), P(B)=1.2P(M);
$$
$$
P(J)+P(B)+P(M)=1;
$$
$$
\frac{P(B)}{1.2} +P(B)+\frac{P(B)}{1.2}=1;
$$
$$
P(B)=\frac{3}{8}
$$
For some reason the answer is $ \frac{7}{15} $ Can someone help me out here.

Comment: Well....I can get to $\frac 7{15}$ by assuming that was is meant here is that $P(M)=P(J)$ and $P(B)=P(M)+.2$.  That said, I think your interpretation would be the standard one.

Comment: This is a problem stemming from the imprecisions in language. The real question is do you mean 20% more relative to James or 20% more unit as percent of the whole. One gives $1.2 \cdot$ and one is $+ 0.20$ . Economists have different words for percentages to avoid this confusion but ordinary language lacks it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have $P(B) = P(J) + 0.2$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think they meant $20\%$ more as in

$$P(B) = P(J)+\frac15 , P(B) = P(M) + \frac15$$
$$P(B) + (P(B) - \frac15) + (P(B) - \frac15)=1$$
$$3P(B) = \frac75$$
$$P(B) = \frac{7}{15}$$

Comment: The actual wording was 20% higher, but what does $ P(M) +0.2 $  actually mean? Thanks very much for all your help

Comment: It means that probability of hiring bill = probability of hiring michael + 20% or in math language that is $P(B) = P(M) + \frac{20}{100}$

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment Posts I write an answer instead...

The Problem is the mix-up between percentage and percentage points.

**Example**

- Toms chance to win is $10\%$ and Kevins chance is twice as much,
  which means nothing else than Kevins chance is $\color{red}{100}\%$
  higher. $$P(K) = 2\cdot P(T) = P(T)\cdot
     \frac{100+\color{red}{100}}{100} =0.2 = 20\%$$
- Toms chance to win is $10\%$ and Kevins chance is $\color{red}{10}\%$ percentage points higher
  $$P(K) = P(T) + \frac{\color{red}{10}}{100} = 0.2 = 20\%$$